# Плагин для системы управления проектами Trac

Tags: python, trac, плагин

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть желание написать собственный плагин для системы управления проектами `Trac`.

Но вот возникла необходимость получить логины всех пользователей текущего проекта. Есть ли способ их получить независимо от используемого плагина (и типа) авторизации для аутентификации пользователей? Предоставляет ли сам `Trac` подобную "точку расширения"?

Спасибо.

P.S. Хорошо бы админы метку `trac` добавили =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Макрос есть по юзерам: [UserStatsMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/UserStatsMacro).
Начинать копать надо отсюда `self.env.get_known_users()`

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, данный макрос и использует данную функцию.
Её я уже пробовал; к сожалению выводит пустой список, хотя пользователи заведены...

    >>> from trac.env import Environment
    >>> env = Environment('/path/to/trac/environment')
    >>>print [user for user in env.get_known_users()]
    []

Прошу прощения, за свою невнимательность =) Прежде чем использовать данную команду, нужно было привязать к имени пользователя адрес электронной почты и полное имя (это делается самим пользователем в Preferences).
Теперь получаю что нужно!)